# How to "settle" AVS transactions via the SOAP API?

Tags: api, soap, transactions

I integrated our site with Cybersource using the SOAP API.
Everything works perfectly but I am trying to see if I am able to settle an AVS transaction via the API. In the Cybersource Business Center you are able to view an AVS transaction. There is the ability to "settle" the transaction from that view.
How can I use this via the SOAP API?

The reason I need this is I'm building the Cybersource integration with our CRM so our staff doesn't have to log into 2 different systems to do their work. The thinking is that they would process all transactions on the CRM with the integration. Since I would be saving transaction data on my end as well, I am able to create custom reports for them. One of them is an AVS report in which it was requested that they have the ability to "settle" the transaction just like how they are able to from the Cybersource Business Center.

Answer (score 0):

I found this document helpful in creating my own SOAP API integration:

http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/CC_Svcs_SO_API/Credit_Cards_SO_API.pdf

The fieldnames for CyberSource's "Simple Order API" are the same as the ones you need to use for the "SOAP Toolkit API".  So, in order to settle a an authorization that failed its AVS check, you simply need to provide the authorization request ID to settle it like you would any other authorization.  Do this in the ccCaptureService_authRequestID field along with all of the other required fields.  As long as the authorization in question has an authorization code, you should be able to settle it.